# How do I fix this dimenion error in keras / tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model

I am trying to fit a model that predicts a 1 or a 0 for each row of the X array. X is an array of shape (1000,26) and Y is of shape (1000, 1).For whatever reason tf/keras doesn't seem to like my inputs.

So far I have tried changing the input type. It comes in the form of a pickle and then is turned into a numpy array by using the "np.values" function. Before I was using tf.constant(training) instad of X = training.values but all changing that did was give me a slightly different error (both included below)

This is the full code minus the imports and loading of some other data files.

```py
training = pd.read_pickle("./training.pkl")
train_labels = pd.read_pickle("./train_labels.pkl")

X = training.values
Y = train_labels.values
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='relu', input_dim=26))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['binary_accuracy'])


model.fit(X, Y, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=100)
```

The current error:

```py
Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Error message when using tf.constant

```py
Incompatible shapes: [1000] vs. [1000,2]
```

Comment: In the last layer you are using 2 units in the Dense layer. Make it 1 unit so that the output shape is ( None , 1 ) which matches the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to write a comment so I write an answer here.

As @Shubham Panchal has suggested, your last layer must match the shape of your Y. Therefore you either make sure that your Y has shape (1000, 1) and change your last layer to have 1 node, or you one-hot encode your Y (see `pandas.get_dummies`) so that it has shape (1000, 2).

As we were discussing over cross-validated, you don't need to use Tensorflow constants/placeholders/variables here (I suggest to have a look at the differences between them and how Keras handles them). Feeding directly numpy arrays is sufficient since Keras takes care of defining the Tensorflow graph for you.

Also, you convert your pandas dataframe to numpy array using `pandas.DataFrame.values`, however notice that in [its documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) the suggested method is `pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy`.